# which model should be used for calculate the residuals of DV in twin data

Tags: mixed-model, residuals, linear

I want to use the residuals of the dependent variables as new variables for analyses. these variables are continuous mammographic density measures from twin data. so which model should I use for calculating the residuals, mixed-effect linear model or simple linear regression model? the residuals calculated from the two models showed opposite results.

Comment: In general, using the residuals from one model as the dependent variable in another analysis is a bad idea, as there is uncertainty in any regression line and thus there is uncertainty in the residuals themselves.

Comment: Here is an older paper on the topic from ecology: Freckleton, R. P. (2002). On the misuse of residuals in ecology: regression of residuals vs. multiple regression. Journal of Animal Ecology, 542-545.

And another more recent one from finance: Chen, W. E. I., Hribar, P., & Melessa, S. (2018). Incorrect inferences when using residuals as dependent variables. Journal of Accounting Research, 56(3), 751-796.

Comment: I used the residuals for all variables included in the analyses (both DVs and IVs). and there is some theoretical basis behind this. so based on the assumption that I have to use the residuals, which model would you think is more appropriate?

Comment: This is impossible to say without more information. If the mixed-effect model was more appropriate for the data structure then I might say use that, but really there's no reason to be using the residuals.

Comment: When two statistical models give different results, and they are both well-specified models, which one is correct is often not a statistical question, but a theoretical one driven by scientific reasoning

Comment: since its twin data, so i think the linear mixed effect model would be more appropriate to do the analyses. But i was just not sure if i can use the mixed effect model to calculate the residuals.

Comment: thanks so much for your information!

Comment: @sjp, just realised that it might be not a good idea to use linear mixed effect mode to calculate the residuals, if we need to use the residuals as a new variable for further analyses in another linear mixed effect model. as the random effect would also be removed from the residuals. maybe just try to calculate the marginal residuals